# Need help with AsyncTask on listview item button click

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, textview

I need some help with threading in my app.  Ive got an activity that has a listview.  Each listview item has one button and one textview. I would like to have each button click run in its own thread and update the corrosponding textview control on its row.

Im a beginner android developer and would appreciate some input on this.  Ive tried to implament an AsyncTask sub class, but cant figure out how to do it for each button and have it update the textview.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to call the new Instance of the same `AsyncTask` every time you perform a `click` on the item.

```
    OnItemClickListener itemListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long arg3) {
            asyncTaskName newTask = new AsyncTaskName(view , position);
            newTask.execute();
     }
   }
```

view and position are part of constructor because you would like to update the item ,that is what view is for, and position is to do something unique based on position in your asyncTask.

In your asyncTask , you might have to something similar to what i have done below.

```
 private class asyncTaskName extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private View mView;
        private int mPosition;

      public asyncTaskName(View view, int position){
          mView = view;
          mPosition = position;
      }


     protected void doInBackground(Void... urls) {
         // do something you have to here based on mPosition.
         return null;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         // now update the textView here
         TextView tv = (TextView) mView.findViewById(yourTextViewId);
         // now you have reference to tv, probably update the text by
         tv.setText(yourString);
     }
 }
```

HTH.

Comment: this is exactly the help i needed.  Thanks for your direction!